# periodic solutions with constant period

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Recently I am facing a problem which leads to the following type of ODE
$$x'' + x + f(x') = 0.$$

It is obvious that when $f$ is a constant valued function, the solutions are all periodic and have a common period $2\pi$.

I want to know if there is a nonconstant smooth function $f$, such that (1) the solutions are all periodic, and (2) they share a common period $T$.

I have obtained many examples which satisfy the condition (1), for example $f(x)=(\sin x)^n$ for even integer $n>0$.  But none of them satisfy (2).

Comment: Can $f$ also be a function of $t$ like $f(x(t)',t)$, or must it only be a function of $x'(t)$.  I'm assuming $t$ is the independent variable.

Comment: @RobertIsrael by constant valued function, I mean something like $f(y)\equiv 1$.

Comment: @D.B. just a function of $x'$, no $t$ dependence.

Comment: By the way, is this a part of a research problem? What kind of complexity do you expect from the answer?